# C program syntax "({statement;});" is reported as error by keil

Tags: c

I am trying to define a macro in the format

```
#define SUM(x,y) ({log_var = x; log_var += y;})

void main(void)
{
    unsigned int log_var;
    SUM(10,20);
}
```

Compilation of the same by ARMCC throws an error "Expected an expression" but compilation with GCC doesn't throw the error.

Is it the syntax `({<statements>});` is not allowed in ARMCC or is there any other reason for the same ?

The same disappears when the parentheses is removed. i.e `{<statements>}`

Comment: It is a GCC extension.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have a multi-statement macro body, the usual way is to have a one-iteration `do while` loop:

```
#define SUM(x,y) do {log_var = x; log_var += y;} while (0)
```

Comment: But he could as well use brackets only, couldn't he?

Comment: @Mauren That would cause empty statements if the OP adds a semicolon after the macro "call", and not all code verifiers like empty statements.

Comment: Oh, I haven't noticed that.